# Postgres/netezza multiple join from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, join, netezza

Hi I have a problem when migrating from ORACLE to Netezza, netezza seems to have problem if multiple tables is declared before using JOIN`s. How could I write this join differently ?

```
INSERT INTO...
SELECT...
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2   //here seems to be the problem as postgres dont allow to put two tables in FROM clause if there are JOIN`s involved
JOIN talbe3 t3 ON t2.column = t3.column
JOIN table4 t4 ON t2.column = t4.column
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 t5 ON (t4.column=t5.column AND t4.column=t2.column AND t4.column=t3.column)

WHERE....;
```

Comment: Is there a condition (or more) in the WHERE clause that joins table1 to table2?  If so convert it to a JOIN.  If not use `table1 cross join table 2`.

Comment: No they are not joined in WHERE clause.
Do you suggest doing:
`FROM table1 t1
 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
JOIN.. JOIN..`?

Comment: Yes if a Cartesian product of these 2 tables is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply should not mix old-style (implicit) and new-style (explicit) joins.  In fact, a simple rule is simply to avoid commas in the `from` clause.

I imagine the problem that you have is a scoping problem for the table aliases.  I know this happens in MySQL.  But, because I *never* use commas in `from` clauses, I am not aware of how this affects other databases.  I think the part of the `from` clause *after* the comma is parsed as a unit, and the aliases defined before are not known during this parsing stage.

In any case, whatever the problem, the simple solution is to replace the comma with `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO...
SELECT...
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2   //here seems to be the problem as postgres dont allow to put two tables in FROM clause if there are JOIN`s involved
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.column = t3.column
JOIN table4 t4 ON t2.column = t4.column
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 t5 ON (t4.column=t5.column AND t4.column=t2.column AND t4.column=t3.column)

WHERE....;
```

This should work in all the databases you mention -- and more.

Comment: Thanks, the procedures im exporting wasnt written by me so I didnt understand fully how that stuff from FROM teble1,table2 worked. Ws confusing for me with all the joins. Your explenation cleared my mind.